# d3.js fluid design, different browsers are behaving with big difference

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, fluid-layout

For the example below, if I run it, chrome and Firefox give me about same size of pie chart at about same position. If I run it with IE 11, then the size is too small and the position is way off to left. If I run it with Safari 5, then the size is about the same as chrome and Firefox but the position is way off to below. I was wondering how can I fix the code so that all 4 browsers display the visualization in about the same way? Thank you.

Javascript:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="pie.css">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<div id="pieChart"></div>
<div id="pieChartLegend"></div>
<script src="d3.min.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
<script src="JQuery.js" charset="UTF-8"> </script>
<script src="spin.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
<script>
var dataset = {
    apples: [53245, 28479, 19697, 24037, 40245],
};

var width = 1800,
        height = 310,
        radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

var color = d3.scale.category20();

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
        .sort(null);

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
        .innerRadius(radius - 100)
        .outerRadius(radius - 50);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + width + " " + height)
        .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMidYMid meet")
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(150,150)");

var path = svg.selectAll("path")
        .data(pie(dataset.apples))
        .enter().append("path")
        .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); })
        .attr("d", arc);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#pieChart{
position: absolute;
top:    13%;
left:   1%;
min-width:100%;
}
```

Update:
I found if I change to following code, then the size of IE 11 will be same as Chrome and Firefox, and this solve the issue of positioning of Safari too. So right now the Firefox, Chrome, Safari, are behaving alike, but IE11 positioning is too much off. And I wonder why this change can solve the issue. Thank you!

```
var svg = d3.select("#pieChart").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + width + " " + height)
        .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMidYMid meet")
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(150,150)");
```

Comment: Have you tried applying a css reset? For instance: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: I just tried and it doesn't seem to give any changes, please see my update of question. Thank you!